How to filter data from list of objects from response?
I have a response. I need to get the functionAmount when functionType = limit. I have the hard coded here. How to convert this into dynamic. How to filter data from nested objects?
"users": [
    {
        "userId": "78888",
        },
        "functions": [
            {
                "functionCriteria": {
                    "functionParameter1": "GLOBAL",
                    "functionId": "77888"
                },
                "functionAuthorities": [
                    {
                        "functionType": "INITIALIZE",
                        "functionAmount": "250",
                     
                    },
                    {
                        "functionType": "LIMIT",
                        "functionAmount": "2500",                           
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

if (response != null) {
  List<UserOutput> users = response.getUsers();
if(users.size() > 0)
  {
    List<FunctionAuthorityInfo> functions = users.get(0).getFunctions();
    if (functions.size() > 0)
     {
        List<FunctionAuthority> functionAuthorities = 
        functions.get(0).getFunctionAuthorities();
       if(functionAuthorities.size() > 0)
          {
             String s = functionAuthorities.stream()
                        .filter(functionAuthorities -> 
              functionAuthorities.getFunctionType().equals("LIMIT"))                      .map(FunctionAuthority**::**getFunctionAuthorityAmount()) //NOT WORKING
.get();
}
}
}
}


You can loop through functionAuthorities and then apply the condition of checking for LIMIT, then you can get the function amount for all.

... Or use the .filter() method after you convert your list to a stream:)

How to loop through functionAuthorities?

Please help me in updating my code dynamic. How to make the functionAuthority dynamic?

How to loop through functionAuthorities and functions?

return functionAuthorities.stream()
        .filter(functionAuthorities -> functionAuthorities.getFunctionType().equals("LIMIT"))
        .mapToInt(FunctionAuthority::getFunctionAmount)
        .get();

Using Java's Stream API should do its job, without requiring you to manually navigate through each FunctionAuthority and checking if their type is LIMIT through an if statement.

List functions = users.get(0).getFunctions();
List functionAuthorities = functions.get(0).getFunctionAuthorities();
String functionType = functionAuthorities.get(1).getFunctionType();
please update these to dynamic. Users contains functions list. functions contains functionAuthorities list. get functionAmount when functionType = limit.

how to make this dynamic  List functionAuthorities = functions.get(0).getFunctionAuthorities();

@TestUser my approach is dynamic. It loops through all function authorities

Hi Mario, Would you please update my original code. not sure exactly where i need to update.

Hi Mario, I updated the code with your suggestion. Currently FunctionAuthority**::**getFunctionAuthorityAmount() is not working. Invalid Assignmnet operator. Please see if i updated th code properly or not.
